# How to use audio units in an application

Tags: objective-c, audio, core-audio, audiounit

I've been looking for things online that teach how to use audio units in an application, with no luck. I'm trying to make an application that allows the user to apply AUTimePitch to the playback of audio files, on the fly. But i can't find anything online to teach a total beginner how to use audio units.

also, i'm making this for mac, not iOS

Answer (score 12):

The best document by far on the subject is Apple's [Audio Unit Hosting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) for iOS in the dev library. For a more general introduction, you can check out the [Core Audio Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html).

I also found the [MixerHost](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MixerHost/Introduction/Intro.html) and [iPhoneMultichannelMixerTest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneMultichannelMixerTest/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009113) sample code incredibly helpful in starting to use audio units.

Finally, I find class references and service references like the [Audio Unit Processing Graph Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AUGraphServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007289) and the [Audio Unit Component Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioUnit/Reference/AUComponentServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) useful for exploring the functionality of particular methods, constants, classes, and so on.

**Edit:** I realized that your question doesn't say whether you're working in Mac OS or iOS. This answer is obviously heavily iOS-centric. Could you edit your question to tell us what environment you're in?